# Robot Framework -Error when trying to connect to SQL sever which is in the cloud (Azure)

Tags: sql-server, azure, robotframework

My string is:

```
Connect to Database  pymssql   ${DBSERVER}  ${DBUsername}   ${DBPassword}   
${DBHost}   ${DBPort}
```

Error is:

> OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (xxxxxxxxxxx:1433)\n')

I am using the following lib in my resource:
Library    DatabaseLibrary  
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    String

I have tried with NO Proxy and with a Proxy - same error.

Comment: Did you set the SQL database [firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule)? Library looks well, ref: [MSSQL_DB_Tests.robot](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/blob/master/test/MSSQL_DB_Tests.robot).

Answer (score 2):

Connect To Database Using Custom Params  pymssql      ${DBSERVER}  ${DBUsername}   ${DBPassword}  ${DBName}   ${DBPort}

Use this format it's working Fine

Answer (score 0):

What versions of that libraries are you using?

Did you install pymssql?

Comment: This should be a comment, not a answer.